# Reemplazar espacio duro (Non breaking space) en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, .net

Buen día, he estado tratando de remplazar una cadena de texto que tiene espaciado duro o non breaking space, pero no lo consigo de ninguna manera, he intentado con los siguientes códigos en una función y nomas no funciona con ninguno:

```
Private Function RepChar10(ByVal text As String) As String
    Dim toChange As String
    toChange = text
    toChange = toChange.Replace("\u00A0", " ")
    toChange = toChange.Replace(Chr(160), " ")
    toChange = Replace(Replace(text, "&nbsp", ""), "nbsp", "")
    toChange = Replace(Replace(text, Chr(10), " "), Chr(13), " ")
    RepChar10 = toChange
End Function
```

Si alguien supiera una forma de eliminarlo, muchas gracias de antemano!

Saludos!

Actualizacion, solucion:
Que tal, lo solucione dejando el codigo de la siguiente manera:

```
Private Function RepChar10(ByVal text As String) As String
    Dim toChange As String
    toChange = text
    toChange = toChange.Replace(",", " ")
    toChange = toChange.Replace(Chr(160), " ")
    toChange = toChange.Replace(Chr(13), "")
    toChange = toChange.Replace(Chr(10), "")
    RepChar10 = toChange
End Function
```

el único detalle es que reemplaza los acentos y las ñ por otros caracteres, pero creo que es lo de menos

Comment: ojo que estas usando solamente los ultimos dos. Como ves vos el espacio en tu archivo? tenes un ejemplo?

Comment: que tal, gracias por la respuesta, debido a ella me puse a probar combinando la ultima linea con la de char(160) y me funciono, lo único malo es que los acentos y las ñ me las cambia por otros caracteres

Comment: Para estos dos: toChange = toChange.Replace(Chr(13), "") Y toChange = toChange.Replace(Chr(10), "")  puedes usar trim: toChange.Trim(Chr(13)) Y toChange.Trim(Chr(10))